# optim with inequality constraint

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, solver

I am attempting to use `optim()` in R to solve for lambda in the following equation:

> lambda/sigma^2 - ln(lambda/sigma^2) = 1 + 1/Q

subject to constraint :

> lambda > sigma^2.

I am not sure how one goes about setting up this in R.

I am open to alternative optimization routines as well although the equation seems convex and therefore `optim` should be a fine choice.

Thank you!

Comment: Is lambda the only variable? If you check the "note" in `?optim` for one-dimensional problems `optimize()` is recommended instead. And when you say "solve for lambda", is there an equality (or inequality) missing from your equation? Or do you want to minimize or maximize your expression?

Comment: I updated the equation (I had a typo). Yes, it is a one-dimensional problem. I will explore optimize() - thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to solve an equation. Whether or not the constraint is met, can only be decided ex post.
You can use `uniroot` as follows

```
f <- function(x,sigma=1,Q=1) {x/sigma^2 - log(x/sigma^2) - 1 - 1/Q}
uniroot(f,c(1,5))
```

giving

```
$root
[1] 3.146198

$f.root
[1] 3.552369e-06

$iter
[1] 5

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

Comment: Additional remark: as long as Q>=0 a solution for x will always be >=sigma^2.

Answer (score 1):

Decided this is more an answer than a comment.

Both `optim` and `optimize` minimize functions, so what you want to do is write an error function that returns, say, the squared error for a given lambda (`se(lambda, sigma^2, Q)`, make sure your lambda is the first argument). Then call `optim(f = se, lower = sigma^2, sigma^2, Q)` and it will return the value of lambda that minimizes your error function. If you have multiple data points (Q, sigma^2 pairs) then make your function a sum of squared errors or try using `nls()`.